# Conditional weighting for SparseCategoricalCrossentropy in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tensorflow2.0

We are working on an extractive text summarization task in TensorFlow. We have been able to get a baseline model up and running. Now, to get a more holistic model what we want to do is to be able to compensate for the padded sequences and at the same time give more preference to the sequences that are summary candidates originally.

Here's what we have done so far:

```py
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True, reduction='none')

def loss_function(real, pred):
    # account for the padded sequences
    mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(real, 0))
    
    # account for the summary tags
    important_tags = tf.math.equal(real, 2)
    
    # calculate the original loss
    loss_ = loss_object(real, pred)
    
    # compensation scheme
    mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss_.dtype)
    important_tags = tf.cast(important_tags, dtype=loss_.dtype)
    loss_ *= mask # for the padded values
    loss_ = 3 * important_tags # for giving more weightage to the summary candidates

    return tf.reduce_mean(loss_)
```

This results in the ***gradients not found error***. Any directions to remedy the situation, in general, or even a better approach toward conditional weighting with `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify your inputs, I had tried to reproduce this error but got answer without any error.
For input, I've used

> ```
> real = np.random.rand(1,20).round()
> pred = np.random.rand(20,20).round()
> ```

Comment: My inputs are in the shapes of (64, 29) with values 0, 1, 2.